# KnockoutJS - Multiple partial views within on main view?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, knockout.js

I am trying to port an existing asp mvc app over to use knockoutjs (pure js/html) as I no longer really need any of the functionality within asp mvc. However one problem I can forsee is the way I am handling some of my pages.

I have one page which contains about 12 partial views, each partial has its own model. Now with Knockout JS it seems like you should only really have 1 viewmodel/view per page, however the page I have contains a large amount of information, the sections would be akin to:

- Customer Details
- Customer Address
- Customer Recent Orders
- Customer Cards
- Customer Funds
- ...

To make things more tricky if some details change in on part, it needs to change data in another part. So lets say you remove a card it then needs to tell the funds control that it no longer has a card so wont have funds. (This is all an abstract example, but hopefully illustrates the point)

So I am a bit unsure how to do this in knockout, as that would rather have it as one big model, which I would be happy with doing but it contains ALOT of information. As well as multiple forms, as you can update your address without having to update everything else.

So should I just make one large model for this view and just deal with it? or is there a way to have views talk to each other?

Comment: Does anyone have any decent tutorials in general for Knockout as I found the documentation a bit to short, and there were only some small examples. Nothing significant like a demo app that showed it working on multiple pages etc...

Comment: Just to add some context to the demo app bit, I found their site had a few decent examples but they only seemed to use a View Model and View, never a model, so what is this other Model all about? as otherwise its just VVM...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My strategy is to use a one large view model. No matter you put it, the partial views are a server-side concept and once everything transfers to the client side, it would be large amount of data information in a single page.

However to make things manageable I ensure that every Javascript manipulation code is written in it's own Partial view. This makes it easier to track functionality and it's respective code.

So basically you populate your main Customers array object in the main page and then call functions to populate Details, Addresses etc. which are respectively defined in each of the partial view.

Comment: Thanks for the response, one thing that still concerns me about the one big model style is that each model within the larger model (i.e Address, Card) are saved independently. However from my initial looking it looked like you persist the whole model at once... do I have to write anything custom to do this? or is it just as simple as exposing saveCard(index) saveAddress(index) as methods that just send that to the server?

Comment: not really. if you have models under a larger model you just have to ensure that you reference them correctly inside the partial views e.g. `<a data-bind="click:Card.addNew">Add Card</a>` . I haven't really tested that though because I ended up putting everything in a single view model. no models inside model; not exactly a great solution.

Comment: Btw, I just realized that you could also apply multiple bindings by encapsulating your partial views inside a div and then calling `ko.applyBinding(partialViewModel, "id of div")` . The second parameter describes where to apply the bindings to.

Comment: Thanks for all the info, should be more than enough for me to work with at the moment.

Answer (score 4):

I would caution against one monster view model because it creates a tight coupling that you'll want to avoid in complex applications.

A better solution is to build a pub/sub system on top of `ko.subscribable`. Communication between view models is then facilitated by managing subscriptions to various events. It's a little more work upfront, but it will pay dividends down the road.

[Here](http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/05/using-ko-native-pubsub.html) is a blog post that expands on the topic. I highly recommend this blog. Its a great resource for knockout-specific challenges and strategies.

Comment: Yeah duder, your right, pub/sub works well in this case. I got 6 small View Models all communicating via a pub/sub library (postbox). Very loose coupling, better for refactoring, testing and reuse.