# WebApi and Knockout patterns within MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, design-patterns, knockout.js, asp.net-web-api

I am having some issues around the patterns needed to bring my application into the WebApi + Knockout world. The following scenario has thrown be a bit.

I have a very basic grid partial view (_grid.cshtml). It uses a GridViewModel, which only has a QueryID. The Grid partial passes the QueryID using Ajax (which is defined in the ko ViewModel) to a WebApi method which returns a collection of objects in JSON. I then use knockout to bind the columns of the grid based on the returned JSON, and then loads the rows in.

This all works fine, but I'm uncertain if this is the correct approach.

```
    // When the query is changed update the grid data.
    self.selectedQueryID.subscribe(function (newQuery) {
        self.SelectQuery(newQuery.ID());
    });

    // Execute the query and set the results as the rows of the table
    self.SelectQuery = function (queryID) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/api/Query/Execute?ID=' + queryID,
            type: 'POST',
            contenttype: 'application/json',
            success: function (result) {
                self.gridData(result);
            }
        });
    };
```

The complexity comes when I have another partial view which is a list of available Queries that a user can choose from. This partial view sits adjacent to the grid partial view. I want to be able to somehow send the clicked query across to the grid so it can then shoot another ajax request off to get the data of the new query. I know this is completely the wrong way to think about an MVC application, but I just don't know enough about WebApi.

```
    @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_Grid.cshtml", Model.GridViewModel)
    @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_Queries.cshtml", Model.User)
```

This is all in an effort to implement some sort of default query for the grid, then give the user the option to select other queries.

I have also started looking into Backbone and Knockback but don't know (enough about them or) if this is the right direction.

Comment: Knockout is a client side MVVM framework, the gluing of data and view should be done on the client only, not both.

Comment: I have some knowledge of Knockout and the MVVM pattern, I am only using knockout for the client side binding.
        <tbody data-bind='foreach: gridData'>
            <tr data-bind='foreach: $parent.gridColumns'>
                <td data-bind='text: $parent[$data["Name"]()]'></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody> this is working fine. I am only having issues with the pattern to incorporate the query partial view into my solution.

Comment: Dont pass any model to the Partial MVC view, it should'nt be dependent on any data since it should be static, the dynamic binding is done on client.

Comment: Thanks for that, I'll take that on board. Any advice on how I might get my queries list to update the grid, considering the queries list can't be in the same view as the grid?

Comment: So I found another question that led me down the right track if anyone else was interested. [KnockoutJS - Multiple partial views within on main view?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6509567/knockoutjs-multiple-partial-views-within-on-main-view) THanks @elDuderino [KO native PubSub for decoupled syncronization](http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/05/using-ko-native-pubsub.html)